# RandomAccessFile from ZipEntry (java)

Tags: java, zip

I was looking for something about reading zip-archives via RandomAccessFile. So, I found this example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.io/RandomAccessFilereadLine.htm
However it doesn't work for me, it tells that there's no such file or directory, but the file-path is right. Is this example incorrect?

UPDATE: from docs.oracle.com:

> `RandomAccessFile(String name, String mode)`
>
> Creates a random access file stream to read from, and optionally to write to, a file with the specified name.

It's weird that they try to create RAF with entryName as a "name" parameter in this example

There's one more example with the same thing: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util.zip/how-to-read-files-within-a-zip-file-3.html

Comment: It feels much more likely to me that you've *actually* got the wrong filename - quite possibly from unescaped backslashes. Have you changed the code *at all*?

Comment: No, I just have changed this string `ZipInputStream zipinputstream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("filename"));` - instead of `filename` I put `/home/123456/archive.zip`

Comment: And that's the line that's throwing the exception? How have you validated that that file exists and is readable?

Comment: no, exception is thrown by this line `RandomAccessFile  rf = new RandomAccessFile(entryName, "r");`
File is readable because it works correct if I use `ZipFile` and its' method `getInputStream(ZipEntry)`

Comment: And this is why it's important to be descriptive in your questions... what is the value of `entryName` when it fails?

Comment: I have absolutely the same code as in the example. My zip-file is readable, and the entry inside is readable either, I've already tested it.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question about the value of `entryName`...

Comment: the value of `entryName` is `"myFile"`

Comment: With no path information etc? (I'm not sure that continuing with comments like this is productive, to be honest...)

Comment: Look at the original example, `String entryName = zipentry.getName();` The `getName()` method returns only entry's inner path, e.g. if I put folder `abc` witch file `def.txt` inside to zip archive and then try to read this entry, `getName()` method will return me `"abc/def.txt"` with no info about absolute path

Comment: Second link now broken, unsurprisingly. Unclear why you would be looking for such a thing in the first place: you certainly won't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a case where un-vetted code winds up on the internets and causes no end of problems.

There is no way the code in those two examples is going to do anything useful.  The only way that code would do anything is if the contents of the zip file had already been extracted into the folder that contains the zip.

Long and short: you can't use RAF with ZipEntry because the ZipEntry refers to a compressed stream.  You can't do random access on a stream (unless you decompress the whole thing and buffer the results).

It's really interesting to me how:

a) the code in the java-tips article doesn't follow proper naming conventions for Java
b) the code in both articles is astoundingly similar

[Here's sample code that shows how to properly use ZipInputStream](http://web.archive.org/web/20090212184031/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/)

Comment: Zip entries are compressed, not encrypted.

Comment: Consider to use the NIO.2 File API instead of working with the low-level ZiPInputStream API. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Puce I've updated to read 'encoded' instead of 'encrypted' (this post is from more than 10 years ago, much has changed - thanks for adding the NIO.2 approach!).

Comment: Encoding is still something else (e.g. UTF-8). Here the data are compressed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)

Comment: Oh, true, it's an old post. Strange that it popped up.

Comment: @Puce ok - I could probably make an argument that 'encoding' is a generic term (i.e. UTF-8 is an example of a charset encoding, but 'encoding' is a very broad term), and over the years, I have absolutely seen 'zip encoding' referenced - but it is more clear to describe the stream as zip compressed, so I'll adjust the wording for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

With the NIO.2 File API (Java 7) working with zip files becomes much easier.

Try (untested):

```
try (FileSystem zipFS =  FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create("jar:" + zipURI), Map.of())) {  
    Path targetInZipPath = zipFS.getPath(targetInZipPathString);  

    // do something here 
}
```

Read more about the ZIP filesystem (JDK module jdk.zipfs) here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html